# Raising errors in the context of python ternary operators

Tags: python, ternary, raise

So let's say that I have all the necessary variables defined and I want to throw an error while assigning a variable with the conditional all in one line:

```
isTestData,isTrainingData,testData,trainingData=True,False,str,int
def whoops():
    raise

a = testData() if isTestData else TrainingData() if isTrainingData else whoops()
```

I'm wondering if there is some builtin function or syntax with raise that I'm not getting... Is defining whoops necessary to get this behavior with a one liner?

Comment: The ternary operator requires that all three operands are expressions, but `raise` is a statement. How about `else 1/0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The basic syntax of **ternary operator(one liner)** in python is:*

```
<expr1> if <conditional_expr> else <expr2>
```

Which requires all the entities enclosed in `<>` to be an **expression**.

**Note:**

- **Expressions can only contain identifiers, operators and literals.**
- **Statements are everything that can make a line/lines of python code.**
- **Its important to note that all the expressions are statements but
  not vice-versa.**

*In your case, you can't use **`raise`** directly in **ternary operator(one liner)**  because it makes a statement.*